# jetpack Compose implement "Home button" functionality on backpress

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have navigation via NavController. For some destinations i clear backstack like

```
navController.navigate(nextScreen) { 
    popUpTo(key) { inclusive = true } 
}
```

and when system "back" button is pressed its returns on home screen. The tray is still holds the app, but when i try continue using the app, main activity destroys and recreates. How can i implement functionality like "system home button" when "system back button" is pressed and backstack is empty? (it means not to destroy activity, but only implicitly call `onPause()` like it works with "system home button")

**UPDATE**

I have a registration flow with 10 screens. On each screen i clear backstack, because of buisness logic. For example, user passed 4/10 of registration flow screens. If he press home button, the app would go to background, and when user return to the app it opens with the same state of 5th screen. But if the user press back button, when he returns to the app the navigations would be from `startDestination` i.e 1 of the 10 screen. I need pass the app to the background like home button do.

Comment: You can't override the `Home` Button Press. It is just way to impractical and so Android Inhibits it. It also ensures the user is protected against malicious apps, by always allowing them to go directly to the home screen by pressing that button, which would be a point of vulnerability if allowed to be intercepted by the people who wrote the app.

Comment: What you seem to need is an in-app navigation system. Just create a bottom-navigation or top-navigation, which is a fairly common practice these days and avoids most of the confusion of system intercepts

Comment: @MARSK An abstract example: supossably i have single activity app with splash screen and login screen. User launch the app, see splash screen and then login screen. On login screen he input some credentials and press system back button (for some reason). I cleared backstack after splash is lanched that is why user goes to home screen. When he return to the app, state have been lost and user must repeat his input. Of course i can persist the activity state, but i think it should not be cleared, when the app is "collapsed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your problem is super-easy, barely an inconvenience. You see, the problem is not that the activity is being cleared on back-press. The real highlight here are the mechanics of Compose. Not gonna stretch it out, simply put - when you press the back button and your activity is "paused", the `Composable`s get destroyed because they are no longer on screen. That is just how Compose is built (for performance) and it makes much sense too. Even if you navigate to another screen inside your app while still inputting your login credentials, and then go back to the login screen, the state would have been cleared, since all those Composables are destroyed the moment they go off-screen.

Now, that's where `ViewModel`s are supposed to help. The state of the `TextField`s that you might be saving within the `Composable`'s body actually needs to be saved inside a `ViewModel`, which persists even configuration changes, i.e., the activity is recreated but the `ViewModel` persists until your app is killed. So, just create a value in the ViewModel, like

`var userName by mutableStateOf("")`

and then pass that as the value of the `TextField`, then update it in the `onValueChange` like you would do with the value defined in the `Composable`.

Easy,

**EDIT**

Actually super-easy, barely an inconvenience -- You see Compose provides a `BackHandler` specifically meant to intercept system back presses. Over there, you could simply call an intent, that triggers an action equivalent to the system `Home` Press. The intent is as follows:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply{
 addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
}.let { startActivity(it) }
```

Easy,

Comment: I suppose i was not fully clear. The example was abstract. Updated the question with reallife problem.

Comment: So, you have a question for me  ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MARSK for answer.
In the end i have somethink like this

```
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val callback = object: OnBackPressedCallback(
        true
    ) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (navController.previousBackStackEntry == null) {
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply{
                    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
                }.let { context.startActivity(it) }
            } else {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }
    context.getActivity()?.let { activity ->
        val dispatcher = activity.onBackPressedDispatcher
        dispatcher.addCallback(activity, callback)
        navController.setLifecycleOwner(activity)
        navController.setOnBackPressedDispatcher(dispatcher)
    }
```

Comment: The recommended way of handling back-presses is indeed the `BackHandler` Composable though. You should use that instead. look it up.